# Scala pattern match case class instance with arbitrary number of None fields

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, case-class

Let's say I have the following snippet of Scala

```
case class A(a: Option[String], b: Option[String])
val v: A = A(None, None)
val vOp: Option[A] = v match {
  case A(None, None) => None  // can I make this simpler / more generalized
  ...
}
```

Is there a way for me to pattern match when an instance of `A` contains all `None` values without explicitly typing out each one?

e.g. I'm looking for something *along the lines* of `case A(None :_*) => None`, but I know that's not syntactically valid.

**Context**
My use case is that I am pattern matching a case class with many underlying fields that changes frequently so I'd like to avoid needing to enumerate all the potential `None` values if possible.

Comment: No, not possible. - If you don't want to enumerate the fields, don't use pattern matching. Maybe you want to solve the problem using generic programming techniques, but the trade-off in complexity may not be worth it.

Comment: You could define something like `Empty[A]` type class, then write type-class derivation for it, then, if your type can be derived for `Empty`, create an empty value and compare against it: `val emptyA = Empty.of[A]; myValue match { case \`emptyA\` => ... }` but it isn't worth the effort if you aren't doing that very often.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you *could* do something like this:

```
object Empty {
   def unapply(p: Product) = p.productIterator.forall(_ == None)
}
```

Then you can write:

```
   A(None, None) match { 
     case Empty() => "is empty"
     case _ => "not empty"
   }
```

But for the record, I don't think this is a very good idea. You say you need this, because there are many fields, and they change often. But then the "base case", when everything is `None` is the least of your problems. When some fields are *not* `None`, what are you going to do? What usefu logic can your `match` statement possibly have, if you don't know what fields are there, not even just *how many* fields there are?